# How can I call setsid()?

Tags: rust

I'm looking at a way to detach a sub-process in rust. Although as per default behavior it is detached, but it will not create a new session as in Posix `setsid()` call.

Generally a pre_exec pattern is used between `fork()` and `exec()` calls to set session id. But the os/unix/process/CommandExt is not exposing such interface to issue syscalls in [CommandExt](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.CommandExt.html)

Is there a way to issue Linux syscalls in Rust?

Comment: Rust is able to call C functions, so you can call `setsid` directly (see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html))

Answer (score 2):

[The libc crates exposes bindings to, well, the libc](https://docs.rs/crate/libc/0.2.70).